# KivyMD MDList spacing layout problem after removing and readding widgets

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7, kivymd

I am building a application with KivyMD. I have a function which makes a list with MDLabels. After the initialization of the list i want to 'refresh' the list with the latest data. Therefore i use clear_widgets() to remove the labels from the list, and then i rebuild the list with new data.

The problem is that the spacing seems te be disturbed once the list is being rebuild. I have tried noumerous things, but i cannot figure out where the problem lies in this situation.

Does somebody know what is wrong here? I have reproduced a simpel example of the matter below.
Many thanks in advance!

kivy version = 2.0.0,
kivymd version = 0.104.1, python 3.7

main.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_file('kivy.kv')

        return screen

    def make_list(self):
        self.root.ids.button.text = 'Click me again'
        if self.root.ids.list.children:
            self.root.ids.list.clear_widgets()

        if not self.root.ids.list.children:
            for i in range(9):
                self.root.ids.list.add_widget(MDLabel(text='Label' + str(i)))


MainApp().run()
```

.kv file

```
Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'

        FloatLayout:

            MDLabel:
                text: 'Click the button below for a list'
                halign: 'center'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .6}

            MDFlatButton:
                id: button
                text: 'button'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .4}
                on_release: app.make_list()

        FloatLayout:
            MDList:
                id: list
                spacing: 40
                pos_hint: {'center_x': .7, 'center_y': .6}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to decipher how `MDList` and `MDLabel` are calculating their heights, but you can fix your problem by specifying the `height` of each `MDLabel`. One way is like this:

```
self.root.ids.list.add_widget(MDLabel(text='Label' + str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=15))
```

Comment: This solves my problem! Thank you very much for your effort.